# Formating Kingston USB

Tags: tails

I have a Kingston flash drive and I want to install Tails. But I read somewhere that when you install an OS on a Kingston flash drive, it can't be changed back to a regular flash drive. If I install tails, would I be able to format that flash drive to what it was, or it is permanent? Or do I need to have a USB stick just for Tails?

Comment: Where did you read "that when you install an OS on a Kingston flash drive, it can't be changed back to a regular flash drive"? Noting your source could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Installing tails does not destroy your usb stick.

The tails documentation explains how to uninstall tails from your usb stick,
see this link:

[Uninstalling Tails or resetting a USB stick or SD card](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/reset/index.en.html)

It has instructions for Windows, Linux and Mac.